# Facebook Credits Refund

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to process my first refund via the Credits API. But I have no idea how to go about it. Any help guys.

I actually got something here. But I did not understand how to go about it.
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=86467

Comment: Can you come up with a more specific question?  We're happy to help with answerable programming questions, but this sounds a lot more like "please build this for me?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used this in the command line

curl -vv -F refund_reason='User says unable to use app' -F status=refunded -F message=Refunded -F params='{comment="user unable to use app"}' 'https://graph.facebook.com/orderidhere?access_token=accesstokenhere'

And its worky!!!!!!